# Check boxes bottom border is not visible in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

[image][image: Checkbox is not visible properly in internet explorer]

Check boxes are working fine in chrome but not in internet explorer.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="patient-div-w" style="width: 9.5vw;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="edema" class="input-checkbox-l">
  <label class="label-n" for="edema" style="line-height: 8vh;">Edema</label>
  <br>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 0px;
}

.input-checkbox-l[type="checkbox"] + label {
    background-image: url(../images/unchk.png);
    background-size: 1.2vw;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 1.7vw;
    background-position: 0vh 0vw;
    width: 8vw;
    margin: 0vw;
    position: relative;
    top: -.1vh;
    left: -1.6vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: "Roboto Regular";
}


.label-n {
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #000;
}
```

The same is the problem with radio buttons.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where are the style properties for the containing element (`.patient-div-w`)? Is there an `overflow: hidden` statement declared for this element?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError that might be the case here, I guess

Comment: .patient-div-w has the following properties-float:left,display:inline-block

Comment: try px instead of vw or vh

Comment: @Sree11, Can you upload the image link (unchk.png)

Comment: Did you try the CSS property 'vertical-align' ?

Comment: added the image...

Comment: Try using top - 0vh

Comment: why everything is in `vw` units? If you are trying to make it responsive, it won't look good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Lets assume the parent of `.patient-div-w` is `.parent-div`. So we need to do the following:

```
.parent-div{
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

This is a very common issue. You can read more about it [here](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
In your code

`<label class="label-n" for="edema" style="line-height: 8vh;">Edema</label>` Just remove inline `style="line-height:8vh;`. it will work.

you can use below code as a reference and it will work IE, FF, Chrome

```
.input-checkbox-l[type="checkbox"] + label {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0px 20px 0px 55px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAkMC.png) no-repeat center left 5px;
  background-size: 30px;
  font-size:22px;
  margin-right:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You can try without image

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
 border:1px solid blue;
  outline: none;

}

div{
  display: inline-block;
}

div span{
vertical-align: super;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<input  type="checkbox" name="" value="1"><span>Label name</span>
</div>
```